# "Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference" Error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When I run this code for updating my likedOne column and making it empty ("")....

```
    $sql11 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE UserData SET likedOne=? WHERE username=?");
    $sql11->bind_param('ss',"",$Username);
    $Username = "netsgets";
    $sql11->execute();
```

I get this error....

```
1 Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /xxx/xxx/xxx/test.php on line 36.
```

The line is....

```
$sql11->bind_param('ss',"",$Username);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The error message clearly states that the second parameter (`""`) cannot be passed by reference. Only variables can be passed by reference, so you should create a variable, and pass it as the second parameter instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use a variable , `bind_param` takes only variable not values directly.

```
   $likedone ="";
   $sql11->bind_param('ss',$likedone,$Username);
```

Answer (score 1):

`bind_param(...)` expects its param parameters as references. [See](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). That means it might change them (e.g. when they refer to a result of the query). Whenever you pass something as a reference you have to give it a name (sloppy rule of thumb, but makes it easier to explain). In a way this just tells PHP that you care about the potential modification (again simplified). You can use `$emptyString = ""; $sql11->bind_param('ss',$emptyString ,$Username);`

Answer (score -2):

sorry for my previous answers

you could fix it up by changing

```
 $sql11->bind_param('ss',"",$Username);
```

to

```
$variable ="";
$sql11->bind_param('ss',$variable,$Username);
```

because bind_param works better with variables

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: i just edited my answer

Comment: Nope. Still not working

Comment: OP is only binding to two "strings", so adding another `s` will not change anything